# .net Maui Community Toolkit - Observable Object - not able to update view

Tags: c#, observable, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am learning .net Maui and have not had a lot of experience with Xamarin or .net Maui.  Could use some hints on Observable Objects and Properties

I have an AddLogEntry page with an associated AddLogEntryViewModel (which inherits from BaseViewModel which in turn inherits from ObservableObject, which is used to add a new log entry.

The view model has the following RelayCommands:

1. *AddLogEntry* - uses LogEntryService to abstract from the database stuff
2. *GetCurrentPosition* - uses Maui IGeolocation to get a current position from the device and intended to update the location in the view.

When the view is opened it gives me a new instance of LogEntry and correctly gets the current date and time and displays AddLogEntryPage

However, when I call GetCurrentPosition from the page using Command="{Binding GetCurrentPositionCommand}" attached to a button I have done something wrong.

I can see by adding appropriate breakpoints that the current location is being returned and appropriate properties of the LogEntry object are updated.  However, the view is not updated with this information even though I think it is bound to the appropriate properties of LogEntry.

I have added the View, ViewModel, BaseViewModel and LogEntry class below.

If I save the LogEntry the correct geolocation information is added to the database but not ever displayed dynamically in the view.

I suspect I have misunderstood something - any hints about what I am doing wrong?  I hope I have been clear enough - happy to provide anything additional.

**AddLogEntryPage (XAML)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Logbook.Views.AddLogEntryPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:gl="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Logbook.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Logbook.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="viewmodel:AddLogEntryViewModel">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <converters:DayOfMonthConverter x:Key="dayOfMonthConverter"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <!-- Date and Time -->
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Date and Time" Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"/>
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <DatePicker VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                Style="{StaticResource MediumDatePicker}"
                                Date="{Binding LogEntry.EntryDateTime.Date}"/>
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}" 
                            Text="at"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <TimePicker VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Format="HH:mm"
                                Style="{StaticResource MediumTimePicker}"
                                Time="{Binding LogEntry.EntryDateTime.TimeOfDay}"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                <!--Line under Log entry date and time-->
                <BoxView 
                        Style="{StaticResource Seperator}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Location -->
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Location" Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Latitude" FontSize="16"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding LogEntry.Latitude}" Placeholder="Enter the Latitude in decimal degrees"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Longitude" FontSize="16"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding LogEntry.Longitude}" Placeholder="Enter the Longitude in decimal degrees"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                  </StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Get Current Position" Command="{Binding GetCurrentPositionCommand}" Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Crew -->
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Crew" Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding LogEntry.Crew}" Placeholder="Enter crew members"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Get Test Crew" Command="{Binding TestCrewCommand}" Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"/>

            </StackLayout>
            

            <!-- Weather Conditions -->
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Weather Conditions" Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"/>
                <Picker Title="Select Weather Conditions" SelectedItem="{Binding LogEntry.WeatherConditions}">
                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>Sunny</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cloudy</x:String>
                            <x:String>Rainy</x:String>
                            <x:String>Windy</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                </Picker>
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Notes -->
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Notes" Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"/>
                <Editor Text="{Binding LogEntry.Notes}" Placeholder="Enter additional notes" HeightRequest="100"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Distance Sailed -->
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Distance Sailed" Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding LogEntry.DistanceSailed}" Placeholder="Enter the distance sailed"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Save Button -->
            <Button Command="{Binding AddLogEntryCommand}" Text="Save Log Entry" Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace Logbook.ViewModels;

public partial class AddLogEntryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    LogEntry logEntry  = new();


    private readonly ILogEntryService logEntryService;

    public AddLogEntryViewModel(ILogEntryService logEntryService)
    {
        this.logEntryService = logEntryService;
        logEntry.EntryDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    async void AddLogEntry()
    {
        var response = await logEntryService.AddLogEntry(logEntry);
        if (response > 0)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Record Added", "Employee Details Successfully submitted", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Not Addedd", "Something went wrong with the Employees Details", "OK");

        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetCurrentPosition()
        {
            try
            {
                var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

                if (location != null)
                {
                    logEntry.Latitude = location.Latitude;
                    logEntry.Longitude = location.Longitude;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle case where location is null
                    // Display an error message or take appropriate action
                }
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException)
            {
                // Handle not supported on device exception
                // Display an error message or take appropriate action
            }
            catch (PermissionException)
            {
                // Handle permission exception
                // Display an error message or take appropriate action
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Handle other exceptions
                // Display an error message or take appropriate action
            }
        }
}
```

**BaseViewModel**

```
public partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(IsNotBusy))]
    bool isBusy;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string title;

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
    }

    
    public bool IsNotBusy => !IsBusy;

}
```

**Model**

```
namespace Logbook.Models
{
    [Table("LogEntries")]
    public partial class LogEntry
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime EntryDateTime { get; set; }

        public string Crew { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        public string WeatherConditions { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public double DistanceSailed { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the view is not updated with this information

This is because your model LogEntry class didn't extend the ObservableObject class. So when you change the peroperty of the LogEntry proerpty in the viewmodel. It will not notify the UI.

So you can try the two solutions:

1. Make the LogEntry class extend the ObservableObject and add [ObservableProperty] on the each property in the LogEntry. But you need to change each value's first letter to lowercase at first.
2. If you just want the `GetCurrentPosition()` command can update the UI. You can create a new instance of the LogEntry class such as `LogEntry temp = new ()` and copy all the properties and the new location to the **temp**. And then you can use the `logEntry = temp`. Because the logEntry is observableproperty, it will notify the ui to update.

Comment: Of course!  Pretty obvious when you think about it!
 I used option 2 as I couldn't get option one to work - but I will experiment with that more later.  Thankyou

Comment: You can refer to the official document about the [Simple property in the ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#simple-property). @cramar

Comment: @cramar Option 1 is very easy if you think about [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and what is the usecase for something like [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper) ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo - thanks that helped.  I hope I did this the correct way.
I ended up creating a similar class that implements ObservableObject that had its fields decorated with [ObserviableProperty]. I use this in my view models and bind to the fields in the views. 

The LogEntry class is decorated with SQLite attributes and a new Class SQLiteService.  This implements IDatabaseService for all the Database work.  

Finally, I used Automapper to map between the two and it all seems to work as expected.  Not sure if this is the best way but it seems to work for me.

Comment: @cramar That is exactly how it should be done.